# IMAP C# Exception thrown

Tags: c#, imap

I'm trying to implement IMAP using C#.

I got the following function:

```
public int MailUnreadCount()
    {
        imapSw.WriteLine("$ STATUS INBOX (unseen)");
        imapSw.Flush();

        string res = Response();
        Match m = Regex.Match(res, "[0-9]*[0-9]");
        return Convert.ToInt32(m.ToString());
    }
```

Then i have on line:

```
return Convert.ToInt32(m.ToString());
```

the following error which says:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
```

Anyone knows what is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does `m.ToString()` return?

Comment: Trying to convert the string that i`ve found on gmail website to integer.

Comment: And what exactly does the `m.ToString()` call return?

Comment: Returns a string that represents the obj m.

Comment: That's right and what exactly that string is? How are we supposed to help if you don't provide the exact value?

Answer (score 0):

You should use like:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(res, "[0-9]*[0-9]");
if (m.Success)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(m.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Looks like m never succeded. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you tell me the value of res variable?